# How do i remove all the letters in a list if it repeats n number of times. where n is a number between 1-10

Tags: list, python-3.x, for-loop

This is the list.

```
list1 =['F', 'L', 'Y', 'W', 'B', 'E', 'G', 'A', 'L', 'K', 'R', 'U', 'B', 'E', 'T', 'L', 'H', 'G', 'E', 'C', 'K', 'Y', 'U', 'B', 'H', 'L', 'U', 'G', 'A', 'F', 'K', 'Y', 'F', 'M', 'P', 'U', 'B', 'K', 'F', 'G', 'I', 'O', 'N', 'S', 'Y']
```

I want to delete the letters that repeat *n* numbers of time. In the context of this problem *n* is 4.

This is what i have tried so far.

```
n = 4
alphabet = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"]
i = 0
for x in range(len(alphabet)-1):
    print(alphabet[i])
    h = list1.count(alphabet[x])
    print("h: ",h)
    if h == n:
        while alphabet[x] in alphabet:
            alphabet.remove(alphabet[x])
print(alphabet)
```

I An getting an error saying that  list.remove(x): x not in list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> to delete the letters that repeat **n** numbers of time

The solution using [***collections.Counter***](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) subclass:

```
import collections

n = 4
list1 =['F', 'L', 'Y', 'W', 'B', 'E', 'G', 'A', 'L', 'K', 'R', 'U', 'B', 'E', 'T', 'L', 'H', 'G', 'E', 'C', 'K', 'Y', 'U', 'B', 'H', 'L', 'U', 'G', 'A', 'F', 'K', 'Y', 'F', 'M', 'P', 'U', 'B', 'K', 'F', 'G', 'I', 'O', 'N', 'S', 'Y']
counts = collections.Counter(list1)
list1 = [l for l in list1 if l in counts and counts[l] != n]

print(list1)
```

The output:

```
['W', 'E', 'A', 'R', 'E', 'T', 'H', 'E', 'C', 'H', 'A', 'M', 'P', 'I', 'O', 'N', 'S']
```

Comment: B,L,k etc... repeats four times. it should be removed. i want the output that says "WEARETHECHAMPIONS".

Comment: @SanjotPreetChandi, I apologize, now it works fine, check my update, *WEARETHECHAMPIONS*

Comment: It works thx for the Code. I am new to python an i would really appreciate if you explain the code. I do not understand what the line "list1 = [l for l in list1 if l in counts and counts[l] != n]" does. as far as i know, its a for loop.

Comment: @SanjotPreetChandi, it's called *list comprehension*. For more extended explanation check this topic https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions. In my solution, the list comprehension was supplied with *if clause* for filtering those letters which fit the requirement

Answer (score 0):

Not to propose whole new solution, you can modify your code to something like this:

```
for x in alphabet:
    print(x)
    h = list1.count(x)
    print("h: ",h)
    if h == n:
        while x in alphabet:
            alphabet.remove(x)
print(alphabet)
```

The problem with your code is that you have a while loop that removes many elements from the alphabet if there is even only one letter that have h = 4 (the element and all forward letters). This is caused by:

```
while alphabet[x] in alphabet:
        alphabet.remove(alphabet[x])
```

when you remove alphabet[x], next element becomes alphabet[x] (indexing must be continuous), so while loop removes one letter and all forward letters.

But as you want to remove letters from list not alphabet you should modify:

```
list1 =['F', 'L', 'Y', 'W', 'B', 'E', 'G', 'A', 'L', 'K', 'R', 'U', 'B', 'E', 'T', 'L', 'H', 'G', 'E', 'C', 'K', 'Y', 'U', 'B', 'H', 'L', 'U', 'G', 'A', 'F', 'K', 'Y', 'F', 'M', 'P', 'U', 'B', 'K', 'F', 'G', 'I', 'O', 'N', 'S', 'Y']

n = 4
alphabet = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"]
i = 0
for x in alphabet:
    print(x)
    h = list1.count(x)
    print("h: ",h)
    if h == n:
        while x in list1:
            list1.remove(x)
print(''.join(list1))
```